# 500 internal server error (only when i try to validate a cart)

Tags: security, authentication, doctrine, symfony-2.1, php-7.4

Hope i don't miss the answer somewhere else, but i get this error since 4 days and can't fix it at all !

I already :

- check and change my .htaccess
- disable .htpasswd
- up my memory limit
- check permissions on file AppCustomAuthenticator / folder Security
- clear symfony cache ( php bin/console cache:pool:clear cache.global_clearer )

I get the same website code in a preprod site and everything work perfectly.
Here it's the log i get in my project/var/log/prod.log :

````
[2021-12-28T09:37:09.236888+01:00] request.INFO: Matched route "app_order_publish". {"route":"app_order_publish","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_order_publish","id":"0","promoId":0,"_controller":"App\\Controller\\ShopController::orderPublish","_locale":"fr-FR"},"request_uri":"https://coedi.sothys.com/fr-FR/order-publish/0/promo","method":"GET"} []
[2021-12-28T09:37:09.251259+01:00] security.DEBUG: Checking for guard authentication credentials. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticators":1} []
[2021-12-28T09:37:09.251274+01:00] security.DEBUG: Checking support on guard authenticator. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\AppCustomAuthenticator"} []
[2021-12-28T09:37:09.251281+01:00] security.DEBUG: Guard authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_key":"main","authenticator":"App\\Security\\AppCustomAuthenticator"} []        
[2021-12-28T09:37:09.257376+01:00] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main","token_class":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Guard\\Token\\PostAuthenticationGuardToken"} []
[2021-12-28T09:37:09.261348+01:00] security.DEBUG: User was reloaded from a user provider. {"provider":"Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Security\\User\\EntityUserProvider","username":"damien.fayol@sothys.net"} [] ```

-> get this one multiple time : 

``` [2021-12-28T09:37:09.275067+01:00] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5Bdcbda2f3a0fd3bed8f8b29c7359e963f%5D%5B1%5D" of type Doctrine\ORM\Query\ParserResult: fopen(/var/www/html/SOTHYS_PROJECT/var/cache/prod/pools/SjD9-+n2v6/f7aa55c94f82): failed to open stream: Permission denied {"key":"%5Bdcbda2f3a0fd3bed8f8b29c7359e963f%5D%5B1%5D","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): fopen(/var/www/html/SOTHYS_PROJECT/var/cache/prod/pools/SjD9-+n2v6/f7aa55c94f82): failed to open stream: Permission denied at /var/www/html/SOTHYS_PROJECT/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:99)","cache-adapter":"Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter\\PhpFilesAdapter"} []
````

````
[2021-12-28T09:37:09.304213+01:00] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Error: "Call to a member function getName() on null" at /var/www/html/SOTHYS_PROJECT/src/Form/OrderType.php line 73 {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function getName() on null at /var/www/html/SOTHYS_PROJECT/src/Form/OrderType.php:73)"} []
[2021-12-28T09:37:09.307952+01:00] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "Symfony%5CComponent%5CHttpKernel%5CController%5CErrorController" of type array: fopen(/var/www/html/SOTHYS_PROJECT/var/cache/prod/pools/OYzS2UwuIb/7223a96d69cc): failed to open stream: Permission denied {"key":"Symfony%5CComponent%5CHttpKernel%5CController%5CErrorController","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): fopen(/var/www/html/SOTHYS_PROJECT/var/cache/prod/pools/OYzS2UwuIb/7223a96d69cc): failed to open stream: Permission denied at /var/www/html/SOTHYS_PROJECT/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:99)","cache-adapter":"Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter\\PhpFilesAdapter"} []
[2021-12-28T09:37:09.308149+01:00] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "Symfony%5CComponent%5CHttpKernel%5CController%5CErrorController%23__invoke" of type array: fopen(/var/www/html/SOTHYS_PROJECT/var/cache/prod/pools/OYzS2UwuIb/7223a96d69cc): failed to open stream: Permission denied {"key":"Symfony%5CComponent%5CHttpKernel%5CController%5CErrorController%23__invoke","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): fopen(/var/www/html/SOTHYS_PROJECT/var/cache/prod/pools/OYzS2UwuIb/7223a96d69cc): failed to open stream: Permission denied at /var/www/html/SOTHYS_PROJECT/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:99)","cache-adapter":"Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter\\PhpFilesAdapter"} []
[2021-12-28T09:37:09.311120+01:00] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"_security_main"} [] ```
````

Comment: check the permission of `/var/cache/prod`

Comment: it was done, but i finaly found ! After add symfony debug, this one tell me i get a problem on an entity who was empty -_-" ! So after a new import of this one with the good value, all works ! 
Thx for your help anyway. And if that can help, symfony debug is rly rly rly helpfull.